# How to include css file in node express?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I know this question has been asked many times but I cannot seem to see what the issue is with my code. I am trying to create a pdf by using a html file. This works but the css file I include is not getting included. I have read through all the previously asked questions and tried the solutions but my issue is still not resolved.
Here is my code.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charest="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello world!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/template.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="document">
            <div class="page" size="A4">
                <h1>testing this!!</h1>
                    {{#each tickets}}
                  <div class="section">
                    <div>
                      <div class="ticketNumber"  >
                        No. {{this.ticketNumber}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="generalStyle">{{this.prizeName}}</div>
                      <div class="generalStyle">
                        Name: {{this.customerName}}
                      </div>
                      <div class="generalStyle">
                        Phone: {{this.customerPhone}}
                      </div>
                        <div class="generalStyle">
                          Address: {{this.customerAddress}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is where I am storing my css file
[image]

and in app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and lastly this is where I create my pdf by sending my html file.

```
  var document = {
    html: html,
    data: {
      tickets: tickets,
    },
    path: "./output.pdf",
  };
  pdf.create(document, options)
    .then(res => {
        console.log("created!!", res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    });
};
```

The file  gets created but the css is not included. Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried a link relative to your html template like `../public/template.css`?  Idealy place the html file and css file in the same folder and use `template.css` as a href for the link element. Alternatively you could insert the css instead of a link. Add to the html following code `<style>%template.css%</style>` and then read the css file and replace the placeholder `html.replace('%template.css%', css_file_content')`.

Comment: Does your `HTML` file locate inside public `directory`?

Comment: @kedarsedai  Does your HTML file locate inside public directory? – kedar sedai 
The HTML was not located in the same folder. I moved it and put both the html and css file directly into the public folder and then changed my script in the html file to <link rel="stylesheet" href="/template.css"> , still no change. I even tried to include a script tag in the head and put my css into in and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use it :=>

```js
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

#### Use it to link stylesheet :=>

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/template.css">
```

- All file are served at "/public/"
- Docs are at  https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
- You Used the statement is used to create a static server it need a index.html
  which is served as 'http://url/index.html' and 'http://url/css/template.css' which can be accessed by index.html. It use '/' route for serving files
- But you are using template engine so it is best practice to specify the path at which you want to serve your static files.